# C# - Padding TabPage to the right

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, tabpage

My `TabPage` overlays the controls of the `TabControl` because it's width is too big. I need to either decrease it's width or pad it to the right.

[image]

(As seen in this picture, the actual `TabPage` overlays the buttons to the left).

Here's my custom `TabControl` class.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FlatUI
{
    public class FlatTabControl : TabControl
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

        private int W;
        private int H;

        protected override void CreateHandle()
        {
            base.CreateHandle();
            Alignment = TabAlignment.Left;
        }

        protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            SendMessage(this.Handle, 0x1300 + 600, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)10);

            base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        }

        [Category("Colors")]
        public Color BaseColor
        {
            get { return _BaseColor; }
            set { _BaseColor = value; }
        }

        [Category("Colors")]
        public Color ActiveColor
        {
            get { return _ActiveColor; }
            set { _ActiveColor = value; }
        }

        private Color BGColor = Color.FromArgb(60, 70, 73);
        private Color _BaseColor = Color.FromArgb(45, 47, 49);
        private Color _ActiveColor = Helpers.FlatColor;

        public FlatTabControl()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
            DoubleBuffered = true;
            BackColor = Color.FromArgb(60, 70, 73);

            Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 10);
            SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Normal;
            ItemSize = new Size(130, 60);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        { 
            this.UpdateColors();

            Bitmap B = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
            Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(B);
            W = Width - 1;
            H = Height - 1;

            var _with13 = G;
            _with13.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            _with13.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            _with13.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
            _with13.Clear(_BaseColor);

            try
            {
                SelectedTab.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= TabCount - 1; i++)
            {
                Rectangle Base = new Rectangle(new Point(GetTabRect(i).Location.X + 2, GetTabRect(i).Location.Y), new Size(GetTabRect(i).Width, GetTabRect(i).Height));
                Rectangle BaseSize = new Rectangle(Base.Location, new Size(Base.Width + 50, Base.Height));
                Rectangle BaseSize2 = new Rectangle(Base.Location, new Size(Base.Width + 50, Base.Height + 30));

                if (i == SelectedIndex)
                {
                    //-- Base
                    _with13.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(_BaseColor), Base);

                    //-- Gradiant
                    //.fill
                    _with13.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(_ActiveColor), BaseSize);

                    //-- ImageList
                    if (ImageList != null && TabPages[i].ImageIndex != -1)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (ImageList.Images[TabPages[i].ImageIndex] != null)
                            {
                                //-- Image
                                _with13.DrawImage(ImageList.Images[TabPages[i].ImageIndex], new Point(BaseSize.Location.X + 8, BaseSize.Location.Y + 6));
                                //-- Text
                                _with13.DrawString("\n\n\n" + TabPages[i].Text, Font, Brushes.White, BaseSize, Helpers.CenterSF);
                                _with13.DrawString("\n\n\nIn Queue", Font, Brushes.White, BaseSize2, Helpers.CenterSF);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //-- Text
                                _with13.DrawString(TabPages[i].Text, Font, Brushes.White, BaseSize, Helpers.CenterSF);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //-- Text
                        _with13.DrawString(TabPages[i].Text, Font, Brushes.White, BaseSize, Helpers.CenterSF);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //-- Base
                    _with13.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(_BaseColor), BaseSize);

                    //-- ImageList
                    if (ImageList != null && TabPages[i].ImageIndex != -1)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (ImageList.Images[TabPages[i].ImageIndex] != null)
                            {
                                //-- Image
                                _with13.DrawImage(ImageList.Images[TabPages[i].ImageIndex], new Point(BaseSize.Location.X + 8, BaseSize.Location.Y + 6));
                                //-- Text
                                _with13.DrawString("\n\n\n" + TabPages[i].Text, Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), BaseSize, new StringFormat
                                {
                                    LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                                    Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                                }); _with13.DrawString("\n\n\nIn Queue", Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), BaseSize2, new StringFormat
                                {
                                    LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                                    Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //-- Text
                                _with13.DrawString(TabPages[i].Text, Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), BaseSize, new StringFormat
                                {
                                    LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                                    Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //-- Text
                        _with13.DrawString(TabPages[i].Text, Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), BaseSize, new StringFormat
                        {
                            LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                            Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            base.OnPaint(e);
            G.Dispose();
            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(B, 0, 0);
            B.Dispose();
        }

        private void UpdateColors()
        {
            FlatColors colors = Helpers.GetColors(this);

            _ActiveColor = colors.Flat;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You already asked this question, deleting content posted by other users is very bad form.  You are coloring outside of the lines, you must observe the bounds returned by GetTabRect().  If you need a bigger tab then just ask for it with the ItemSize property.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @HansPassant suggestion I recreated the TabControl without any tab pages, changed the ItemSize and only then messed with the interior code.